# Heroku: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) /favicon.ico

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I keep encountering this problem when deploying my app. I have tried using  [serve-favicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon) but it hasn't worked.

My project can be found [here](https://github.com/albertothedev/snake-cra) (it's my first MERN stack project and it's not finished, so please don't comment on the code).

I am using [this](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node/tree/master) as a template for deploying MERN stack apps to Heroku.

EDIT: The problem had nothing to do with the favicon. The error displayed in the console was just the result of another thing failing to work properly. In my case, this was the connection to mongoDB Atlas. I changed my database to Heroku's mLab addon for mongoDB and everything deployed perfectly.

This error wasn't being logged on the console so I had to look at Heroku's logs to find what was wrong. See [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) to learn about logging on Heroku.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to add a favicon? If not, this is a common and mostly harmless issue. It won't prevent your application from working, so if you're seeing larger problems they're not caused by the 503 error you mention.

Comment: You were right, what prevented my application from working was another issue that when solved fixed the previous one. I have updated my question with what I learned.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out! [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627) or similar. Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the favicon. The error displayed in the console was just the result of another thing failing to work properly. In my case, this was the connection to mongoDB Atlas. I changed my database to Heroku's mLab addon for mongoDB and everything deployed perfectly.

This error wasn't being logged on the console so I had to look at Heroku's logs to find what was wrong. See Here to learn about logging on Heroku.